# Having trouble getting the SharedPreference number to subtract from a total

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Im developing a calorie app , where the user inputs amount they consumed
and then displays how many calories they have left. I created a xml for the sharedpreferences where the user puts the goal amount.

Problem : getting the Shared Preference to subtract my list-view total.

right now the app is displaying the total amount. which the text-view is called caloriesTotal. Instead of showing the total want for it to show the remanding.

FragmentHome.java

```
 public class FragmentHome extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
      private TextView caloriesTotal;
      private ListView listView;
      private LinearLayout mLayout;
      ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
      CalorieDatabase calorieDB;
      Context context;
      private int foodCalories;
      Button mButton;
      //Database
      private DatabaseHandler dba;
      private ArrayList<Food> dbFoods = new ArrayList<>();
      private CustomListViewAdapter foodAdapter;
      private Food myFood ;
      //fragment
      private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
      private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
      public FragmentHome() {
         // Required empty public constructor
      }
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
      container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, false);
          AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);
          AddEntrybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(1);
              }
          });
      caloriesTotal = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calorie_amount);
      listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListId);
      refreshData();
      return myView;
      }
      public void refreshData (){
      dbFoods.clear();
      dba = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
      ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();
      int totalCalorie = dba.totalCalories();
      String formattedCalories = Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie);
      //setting the editTexts:
      String Prefs="" ;
      caloriesTotal.setText("Total Calories: " + formattedCalories  );
      SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
      editor.putString("prefs_key_current_calorie_amount", String.valueOf(Prefs));
      editor.apply();
      //Loop
      for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){
          String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
          String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
          int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
          int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();
          Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));
          myFood= new Food();
          myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
          myFood.setFoodName(name);
          myFood.setCalories(cal);
          myFood.setRecordDate(date);
          dbFoods.add(myFood);
     }
     dba.close();
     //setting food Adapter:
     foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
     R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
     listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
     foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
         String username1 = username.getString("Username");
         TextView userMain= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);
         userMain.setText(username1);
     }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.AddItems:
         AddEntry addEntry = new AddEntry();
         fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder,addEntry)
         .commit();
         break;
         case R.id.action_settings:
         Intent preferenceScreenIntent = new Intent(getContext(), 
         PreferenceScreenActivity.class);
         startActivity(preferenceScreenIntent);
         break;
         }
     }
}
```

activity_preference.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User Settings">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="Daily Calorie Amount"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount"
            android:summary="@string/prefs_description_daily_calorie_amount" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Dumb question, but can you just retrieve the total calories, subtract the calories consumed, and then store that result back into shared preferences?

It looks like caloriesTotal.setText is showing total calories because you are telling it to do so.  You have the text set to a String + the var formattedCalories.  formatted Calories is defined as Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie)

Comment: I havent tried that. I dont know how to get the value though from the shared preferences. Thats what I wanted to do get the value and just retrieve it back to the total calories. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: This is my first time working with java as well as developing an app. I know may be dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to save and retrieve integers from SharedPreferences:

```
savePrefs("calories", totalCalories);
totalCalories = loadPrefs("calories", totalCalories);

    //save prefs
    public void savePrefs(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();

    //get prefs
    public int loadPrefs(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, value);
    }
```

There's also many examples of similar questions on StackOverFlow that show how to use SharedPreferences.

And here is some documentation on SharedPreferences from developer.android.com:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html